# JQuery slideToggle fixed divs while pushing down rest of conent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a website with a header that is fixed.  Above the header, I have a "login" div at -40px so only the tab "Log In" is showing.  I am attempting to have jQuery push all content (header, container, footer, etc.) down 40 pixels to have the login form visible.  How would I do this?

This is my header.php include:

```
<div id="login" class="full">
            <div id="login-form" class="container">
            <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Log In">
            <input name="password" id="word" placeholder="PASSWORD">
            <input name="user" id="user" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS">

            </div>
            <div id="login-tab" class="container">
                <a href="#">Log In</a>
            </div>
</div>
<div id="header-bg" class="full">

        <header class="container group">
                <div id="logo" class="third">
                           <img src="images/logo-side.png" width="100%"/>
                </div>
                <!--<div id="login" class=" ">
                <form>
                <input name="email" type="text" value="">
                <input name="password" type="text" value="">
                <input name="login-submit" type="button" value="log in">
                </form>
                </div>-->
                <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html" class="active">home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">development</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">availability</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </nav>
        </header>
</div>


        <div id="container" class="container">
```

heres CSS for the login div:

```
#login {
background:#365160 ;
height:40px;
position:fixed;
top:-33px;
z-index:10;
border-bottom:1px solid #ea9919;
font-family:Arial, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
}   
#login-tab a {
background:#365160;
color:#fff;
margin-top:30px;
margin-right:-390px;
padding:0px 15px;
float:right;
border-radius:0 0 2px 2px;  
display:block;  
border-left:1px solid #ea9919;border-bottom:1px solid #ea9919;border-right:1px solid #ea9919;
}
```

The header-bg div:

```
#header-bg {
position:fixed;
top:11px;
background:#fff url(../images/crossword.png) repeat;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px 0px #999;

border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Any suggestions??  I am really lost.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the header is `position: fixed` it will never be affected by other content on the page. You have a few choices:

- Use javascript to push down the content
- Restructure your css/html so that you're not using `position: fixed`, or at least don't have anything above it
- Include the login content with the fixed header, so they're in the same render context